# odbc.ini has AuthenticationMethod=0 even though the db password is encrypted on SPSS server

Tags: authentication, encryption, odbc, spss

I have installed spss modelerserver and sdap on a SUSE linux server. in the sdap folder, there is an odbc.ini file which is used to connect to database by spss server. In this odbc.ini file, there is one *AuthenticationMethod* key which has values *0* or *1*. As per the instructions on this link http://media.datadirect.com/download/docs/odbc/allodbc/index.html#page/odbc%2Fauthentication-method.html%23, *0* is used for no encryption (db password is not encrypted), whereas *1* is used when db password is encrypted.

In my case, even though the db password is encrypted, the db connection is successful only when *AuthenticationMethod* is *0*. This is contradiction to what is mentioned in the link above.

Can anyone please suggest any explanation? Why this is happening.